# Full VCL Class Browser for Delphi

Tags: delphi, oop, ide, components, rtti

Remember the old class hierarchy posters that used to come w/Delphi?

I'm wanting a full class hierarchy browser for ALL my Delphi classes, including the custom ones I've built and installed on the palette, plus third-party components.  Ideally easily searchable by class name (including "whole word only" searches, so partial matches don't count).

I've only seen two things that come close:

1) GExpets Class Browser - Works great, BUT doesn't automatically load ALL installed components / classes, which is what I want.  You have to import all the source units manually, as far as I can tell.... which can be quite a hassle.  It also doesn't allow "whole word only" searches, so sometimes searching for a class w/a common "sub name" takes forever.

2) Eagle / DevExpress CDK -  It loads the full class list automatically, and seems to work brilliantly, but it's only usable in D7 and prior, and it's not *really* focused on being a class browser per se, so much as an "inherit from" chooser.

Is there anything out there which does this already?  If not, how difficult would it be to write an app that, at bare minimum, builds a self-referencing class-name table, so I could at least throw it into a database / treeview component to easily view inheritance / ancestry, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I think [ModelMaker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html) has this feature, but I don't use it

Answer (score 1):

ESSModel is another nice class browser tool, and it's open source.  I don't know if there's any way to get it to load a list of units automatically.  Not sure, but you may be able to manually import all the units you want and then save that as a base project that you start from with all your individual projects.  Not sure how performance would be with that much loaded, or how easy it to view the part(s) you want.

http://essmodel.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need a Delphi IDE Expert (you've mentioned somewhere in your post: *"...installed on the palette, plus third-party components"*), [DelphiDiver](http://www.delphipraxis.net/140771-delphi-2010-rtti-demo-delphidiver%99.html) is good for you (**Source code** available on the [DelphiPraxis](http://www.delphipraxis.net/), registration needed).

#### Look and feel:

[image]

If you feel like delving into the IDE in order to get more indepth details, click `Inspect the IDE` hence the name of the Expert (**DelphiDiver**) ;-)

Click `Inspect the Packages` so as to browse any other third party component(s) or whatever package(s)/component(s) you've installed.

It makes use of the advanced RTTI and requires Delphi 2010 version onward.

I've personally installed it using Delphi XE on my box.

---

I hope it can serve as a base for the more focused **Full VCL Class Browser** you are looking for.